# Explain Guru Parampara of Ramanandacharya

Tags: rama, sri-vaishnava, ramanandi, srisampraday, ramanandacharya

Explain Guru Parampara of **Sri Ramanandacharya** ? Right from beginning.

Comment: Please be a bit more courteous in asking the questions here. The manner in which your question is framed is kinda improper and sort of rude, after all this is not some test paper you are writing for your students.

Answer (score 2):

Guru Parampara Sri Sampraday (Ramanand Sampraday) starts from Sri SitaRam. This is one of the most oldest lineage in Sanātan Dharm whose mentions are found in Vedas, which is continuing till today & will further continue. Few people have a very silly confusion regarding the Sri Ramananda Sampraday that it started when Śrīmad Jagadguru Rāmānandāchārya appeared. But this is false at all. Before Śrīmad Rāmānandacharya, this sampraday was known as alone Sri Sampraday but after their Pravartak Ācharya appeared than they started calling it as Sri Ramanand Sampraday in honour of their Acharya. As lord Śrī Rāma himself appeared as their Ācharya;

रामानन्दः स्वयं रामः प्रादुर्भूतो महीतले ।
कलौ लोके मुनिर्जातः सर्वजीव दयाकरः ॥

Śrīmad Rāmānandacharya was Śrī Rāma himself who appeared on this earth in the form of a great Muni (sage) out of his causeless mercy and compassion on all Jivas

(-Nārad Panchrātra Vaishvānar Samhitā)

Sri Ramanand Saṁpradāya has produced many Maha-Purusha and all of them have served the feet of Maa Bharti  & her sons and daughters. That's why they have such a prestige lineage in which the Ācharya like Sri Sadānandachārya appeared whose disciple was King Pushya Mitra Sungha who has done Ashwa Medha Yagya as Śrī Rām did & stopped the Buddhism spread in India & infact he ordered Pushya Mitra Sungha to remove all culprits from Bhārat who are trying to breach security of our mother land  and this Saṁpradāya also gave Śrīmad Goswami Tulsidas Ji Maharaj who was Incarnation of Mahārishi Vālmīkī. Who wrote Śrīmad Rāmcharit Mānas which let Hindus to Unite against Mughals as Śrī Rām Bhakti always let nationalism to flow in veins.

and also the scholars like Mahārishi Baudhāyan who appeared as their 9th Ācharya who gave Vishistādwāit Philosophy. That phylosophy was further propagated by Sripād Ramanujachārya & Sripād Ramanandacharya. And also Śrīmad Goswami NābhaDas Ji Maharaj who wrote Srimad Bhaktmal and United the whole Sri Vaishnav Community. Please don't be confused, Sri Ramanandacharya & Sri Ramanujacharya belongs to different— different saṁpradāya. Both have different lineage. Don't not interlink each other. One is Sri Ramananda Sampraday and other is Sri Ramanuja Sampraday.

Now let us see the Guru Parampara of Sri Sampraday which starts from Sri SitaRam with 100% accuracy since beginning till today;

First Ācharya of Sri Sampraday is himself Lord Rama who gave Shadakshar Sri Ram Mantra to Śrimati Sita Ji. As Sri Sita Ji (2nd Acharya) has mentioned it herself;

इममेव मनुं पूर्व साकेतपतिर्मामवोचत् अहं हनुमते मम प्रियाय प्रियतराय । स वेद वेदिने ब्रह्मणे स वशिष्ठाय स पराशराय । स व्यासाय । स शुकाय इत्येषोपनिषत् । इत्येषाग्रह्मविद्या ।

It is here that the six-letter Sri Rama Maha Mantra was spoken to me by Sri Saket pati Sri Ramachandra in the divine world saket. I preached to my dearest Sri Hanuman. Sri Hanuman also preached to Sri Brahma, the knower of the Vedas. Shri Brahma also preached to his son Shri Vashishtha. Sri Vashishtha Ji preached to Sri Parashar Ji. Sri Parashar Ji preached to Sri Vyasa Ji. Shri Vyas Ji preached to Shri Shukdev Ji. This is upanishad. This is Brahma Vidhya.

(Atharvaveda Shakha Maithili Maha-Upanishad Chapter 1)

And infact Shadakshar Śrī Rām Mantrā (रां रामाय नमः) is given in Sri Sampraday alone, nobody owns that, this is been proven by Sri Agastya Samhita;

रामानन्द इति ख्यातो लोकोद्धरणकारणः।
आचार्यलक्षणैर्युक्तं वेदवेदान्तपरागम् ॥
श्रीसंप्रदायश्रेष्ठञ्च जनोद्धारपरं सदा ।
विज्ञाय राघवानन्दं लब्ध्वा तस्मात् षडक्षरम् ॥

Sri Ramananda is known as the cause of lifting the world. He is endowed with the characteristics of acharya and is well versed in the Vedas and Vedanta. He is the great (acharya) of Sri Sampraday and is always devoted to the upliftment of the people. He got Shadakshar Mantra (रां रामाय नमः) from his Guru Raghavananadacharya Ji.

(Agastyā Samhitā Chapter 132, Shloka 13, 17)

That's why from scriptural point Ramanand Sampraday alone known as Sri Sampraday. And infact Sri Raghavananadacharya appeared in 1149 CE has wrote in his work;

या श्रियः श्रीस्वरूपा श्रीसम्प्रदायप्रवर्तिका ।
गुरुणां गुरवे तस्यै श्रीसीतायै सुमङ्गलम् ॥

The one who is Sri of Bhagwatï Sri & the one who has started the Sri Sampraday that Guru of Guru. May that Sri Sita ji always be Fortunate.

(Sri Sita Mangal Mala Chapter 1 Verse 109)

Sri Hanuman Ji Maharaj is 3rd Acharya of Sri Sampraday & he has also mentioned that he is been initiated in Vedas;

ऐहिकेषु च कार्येषु महापत्सु च सर्वदा ॥
नैव योज्यो राममन्त्रः केवलं मोक्षसाधकः ऐहिके समनुप्राप्ते मां स्मरेद् रामसेवकम् ॥
यो रामं संस्मरेन्नित्यं भक्त्या मनुपरायणः ।
तस्याहमिष्टसंसिद्ध्यै दीक्षितोऽस्मि मुनिश्वराः ॥
वाञ्छितार्थं प्रदास्यामि भक्तानां राघवस्य तु सर्वथा जागरूकोऽस्मि रामकार्यधुरंधरः ॥

Translation of Main highlights: Lord Hanuman said~ I have taken initiation (Mantra Diksha of Shadakshar Mantra from Śrī Sītā) and I will fulfill the desires of those who engage in chanting mantras with daily devotion and remember Lord Rāma. I will surely grant the desired objects to the devotees of Śrī Raghunāth ji.

(Atharvavedā Shruti Ram Rahasya Upaniṣad 4/10-13)

Sri Hanuman Ji Maharaj is adi acharya of Sri Sampraday and got initiated by Śrī Sita Ji, this has been again cleared;

राज मार्ग मिमं बिद्धि रामोक्तं जानकी कृतम् ।
यदृते चान्य मार्गास्तु चौराणां बीथिका यथा ॥
आद्याचार्य्यं हनुमंतं त्यक्त्वाह्यन्य मुपासते ।
क्लिदयंति चैवते मुग्धा मूलहा पल्लवाश्रिताः ॥
श्रीमैथिल्याश्च मंत्रहि श्रीगुरुं मारुतं महत् ।
सखी भावं दंपतीष्टं भुक्ति मुक्ति प्रदं सदा ॥

Know this (Sri Sampraday) as the Raj Marg because it has been said by Sri Ram & Sri Janaki ji has propagated this, without this other routes are like thieves' street. Those who worship others except the adi acharya, Sri Hanuman, they have pierce the enchanted root and suffer from being dependent on the leaf. Along with Shri Maithili, Shri Ram's mantra is the great Guru of Shri Hanuman……

(Sri Sada-Shiv Saṃhitā, Quoted from Sri Ram Navratna Saar Sangrah Shloka 15–17 by Karuna Sindhu Ji in 1750)

Next, Sri Brahma Ji is 4th acharya of Sri Sampraday, He appeared in Akshaya Navmi Satyuga, He was initiated with Sri Shadakshar Ram Mantra as in Vedas lord Rama has cleared himslef;

त्वत्तो वा ब्रह्मणो वापि ये लभन्ते षडक्षरम् ।
जीवन्तो मन्त्रसिद्धाः स्युर्मुक्ता मां प्राप्नुवन्ति ते ।।
मुमूर्षोर्दक्षिणे कर्णे यस्य कस्यापि वा स्वयम् ।
उपदेक्ष्यसि मन्मन्त्रं स मुक्तो भविता शिव ।।

Lord Rāma said:~Those who take initiation (Disksha) of this Shadakshar mantra (रां रामाय नमः) from you or from Sri Brahma ji, (because Brahmā ji has himself initiated from Shadakshar Ram Mantra) the mantras are proven while alive, after completing body time they attain me by being free from birth and death.

(Atharvavedā Shruti Ram Uttar Tapniye Upanishad 3.15/16)

Infact for Lord Śrī SitaRāma Śrī Brahma Ji has written 100 crore Rāmayan alone in order to praise the glory of his primeval acharya;

वाल्मीकिना तु यत्प्रोक्तं रामोपाख्यानमुत्तमम् ।
ब्रह्मणाभिहितं यच्च शतकोटिप्रविस्तरम् ।।

(Matsya Purana, Chapter 53, Verse 71)

वाल्मीकिना च यत्प्रोक्तं रामोपाख्यानमुत्तमम् ।
ब्रह्मणा विहितं यच्च शतकोटिप्रविस्तरम्॥

(Skandh Purana, Prabhas Khand, Chapter: 2, Verse 95)

Overall meaning is that Śrī Brahmā Ji has written 100 crore Rāmāyana which Śrī Vālmīkī Munī has retold as Valmiki Ramayan.

Next, Sri Vashistha Ji is 5th Acharya of Sri Sampraday appeared in Rishi Panchami, Satyuga who was infact Guru at the time also as Raghavananadacharya when Sri Ram himself appeared as Ramānandacharya;

तारकं मन्त्रराजं तु श्रावयामास ईश्वरः ।
जानकी तु जगन्माता हनुमन्तं गुणाकरम् ।।
श्रावयामास नूनं स ब्रह्माणं सुधियांवरम् ।
तस्माल्लेभे वशिष्ठर्षिः क्रमादस्मादवातरम् ॥
भूमौ हि राममन्त्रोऽयं योगिनां सुखदः शिवः ।
एवं क्रमं समासाद्य मन्त्रराजपरम्परा ॥

Overall meaning is that Sri Janki who is mother of all, she provided mantra to Sri Hanuman Ji than he passed it to Sri Brahmā Ji & Sri Brahma Ji passed it to Vashistha Ji in a descended order.

(Sri Valmiki Samhita Chapter 2 Shlokā 33- 35)

And infact he has spoken about Sri Saket Dham in his Vashistha Samhita which you can access from here:— Vashistha Samhita

Next, Sri Parāshara Ji is 6th Acharya of Sri Sampraday & appeared in Ashwin Shukla 15, Satyuga also guru of Sri Ved-Vyās;

राममन्त्रप्रदं श्रीमद्राममन्त्रार्थ कोविदम् ।
वन्दे पराशराचार्यं शक्तिपुत्रं जगद्गुरुम् ॥ 1 ॥
रामसेवारतं शश्वद् वेदव्यासस्य सद्गुरुम्।
वन्दे पराशराचार्यं शक्तिपुत्रं जगद्गुरुम् ॥ 2 ॥

Who is the giver of the (six-letter) mantra of the Sri Ram, who is the ocean of knowledge and the great scholar who explains the meaning of the mantra of Sri Rama. I salute Acharya Parashar, the son of sage Shakti and the guru of the entire world. I salute Acharya Parashar, the son of Muni Shakti and the world guru, who is engaged in the service of Lord Sri Rama, who is the Sadguru of the eternal Lord Vedavyasa.

(Parāsharastakam verse 1–2)

Sri Parāshara Ji got Shadakshar Ram Mantra from Śrī Vashistha, this has been mentioned in scriptures;

ब्रह्माददौ वशिष्ठाय स्वसुताय मनुं ततः ।
वशिष्ठोऽपि स्वपौत्राय दत्तवान् मन्त्रमुत्तमम् ।।
पराशराय रामस्य मन्त्रं मुक्तिप्रदायकम् ।

Sri Brahmā Ji gave this Shadakshar Ram Mantra to Vashistha Ji than he provided it to Vashistha Ji & Vashistha Ji to Parāshara Ji, hence this (Shadakshar) Ram mantra provides mukti.

(Sri Agastya Samhita, Chapter 8, Verse 2-3)

Not only Shadakshar Mantra but Sri Parāshara Muni is also initiated in Ekashar Ram Mantra & as he has passed to a king;

ततः पराशरमुनिः सर्वानर्थविनाशनम् ।
रामस्यैकाक्षरं मंत्रं तदंते समुपादिशत् ॥
चत्वारिंशद्दिनं तत्र मंत्रमेकाक्षरं नृपः ।
तत्र तीर्थे जजापासौ मुन्युक्तेनैव वर्त्मना ॥
तस्मै नृपतये तत्र ब्रह्माद्यस्त्रं महामुनिः ।
सांगं च सरहस्यं च सोत्सर्गं सोप संहति ॥

Then Muni Parashar provided the king the 'Ekakshara Mantra' of 'Sri Ram Ji' which is the destroyer of all evils. The king chanted the 'Ekakshara Mantra' for forty days in accordance with the ritual………

(Skanda Purana, Brahma Khand 3, Setu Mahatmya, Chapter 12)

And also before giving Shadakshar Ram Mantra to Sri Parāshara Ji Sri Vashistha Ji explained him the Guru Parampara of Sri Sampraday in which Shadakshar Ram Mantra is given;

श्रृणु वदामि ते वत्स ! मन्त्रराजपरम्पराम् ।
यस्याश्च वन्दनाद् रामश्चात्यन्तं हि प्रसीदति ।
सृष्ट्यादौ च सिसृक्षुः श्रीरामविधि विधाय हि । सृष्टये प्रेसयामास वेदं ज्ञानमहानिधिम् ॥ तथाप्यर्थावबोधस्याभावाद्विधिः ससर्जन ।
जातायामीशभक्तीच गुरुभक्तिर्यतो नहि ॥ भद्रिये यचास्ति तत्त्वप्रकाशहेतुता । ततो वेदार्थबोधो न गुरोर्भकेरभावतः॥
ततो रामस्य खेदं हि समुद्वीक्ष्य च मैथिली । गृहीत्वा विधिवद् रामान्मन्त्रराजं षडक्षरम् ॥ हनुमते च दत्त्वा तं राममन्त्रं षडक्षरम् । विधये मन्त्रदानाय प्रेरयामास मारुतिम् ॥

(Sri Vashistha Samhita, Sri Vashistha to Parāshara Chapter 23)

Next, Sri Ved-Vyās is the 7th acharya of Sri Sampraday. He appeared on Guru Purnima Dwapar Yuga. He is in the same lineage this has been mentioned in scriptures;

पराशराय रामस्य मन्त्रं मुक्तिप्रदायकम् ।
स वेदव्यासमुनये ददावित्थं गुरुक्रमः ॥
वेदव्यासमुखेनात्र मन्त्रो भूमौ प्रकाशितः ।
वेदव्यासो महातेजः शिष्येभ्यः समुपादिशत् ।।

The Ram mantra of Parāshara Muni provide liberation which Sri Ved Vyās got through Guru Parampara. The mantra was revealed to the earth by the mouth of Veda Vyasa. The effulgent Vedavyasa taught them to his disciples.

(Sri Agastya Samhitā, Chapter 8, verse 3-4)

And how Śrī Ved-Vyās was able to write such huge scriptures such as ved, vedant puran, Brahma Sūtra etc. click here to know:— How Ved-Vyas wrote?

Next, Sri Sukadēvacharya Ji is 8th Acharya of Sri Sampraday who was the commentator of Śrīmad Bhāgwatam. He appeared on Sravana Shukla 15, Dwapar Yuga;

इममेव मनुं पूर्व साकेतपतिर्मामवोचत् अहं हनुमते मम प्रियाय प्रियतराय । स वेद वेदिने ब्रह्मणे स वशिष्ठाय स पराशराय । स व्यासाय । स शुकाय इत्येषोपनिषत् । इत्येषाग्रह्मविद्या ।

(Atharvaveda Shakha Maithili Maha-Upanishad Chapter 1)

According to above Shlok the lineage is. Sri Ram — Sri Janki — Sri Hanuman —Sri Brahmā — Sri Vashistha —Sri Parāshara — Sri Vyās — Sri Sukadēvacharya

And one more interesting thing is that in whole Śrīmad Bhāgwatam Sri Sukadēvacharya Ji has taken one time Sharnagati & that too of alone Śrī Rām as he was in his lineage;

यस्यामलं नृपसद:सु यशोऽधुनापि गायन्त्यघघ्नमृषयो दिगिभेन्द्रपट्टम् ।
तं नाकपालवसुपालकिरीटजुष्टपादाम्बुजं रघुपतिं शरणं प्रपद्ये ॥

Lord Rāmacandra’s spotless name and fame, which vanquish all sinful reactions, are celebrated in all directions, like the ornamental cloth of the victorious elephant that conquers all directions. Great saintly persons like Mārkaṇḍeya Ṛṣi still glorify His characteristics in the assemblies of great emperors like Mahārāja Yudhiṣṭhira. Similarly, all the saintly kings and all the demigods, including Lord Śiva and Lord Brahmā, worship the Lord by bowing down with their helmets. Let me offer my obeisances unto His lotus feet. I take the refuge of Sri Raghupati.

(Srimad Bhāgwatam Mahāpurān 9.11.21)

Next, Mahārishi Baudhāyan (Bodhayan) Sri Purushottamacharya is 9th acharya of Sri Sampraday who is also the founder of Vishishtadwait phylosophy through his Bodhāyan Vrittï, he wrote many scriptures he was appered in Kaliyuga, in Mithila, Bihar in around 625 BC.

He got initiated in Sri sampraday by Sri Sukadēvacharya as he mentions this in his work, Sri Rāmāyaṇa Rahāshyam;

शुकदेवं गुरुं नत्वा श्रीमद्व्यासं च राघवं ।
रामायणरहस्यं हि सद्बोधाय ब्रवीम्यहम् ॥

And Maharishi Bodhāyan in his Purushottam Prapattishatkam says;

रामिति बीजवान् नाथ मन्त्रराजो हि तारकः
तं जपामि तब प्रीत्यै पाहि मां पुरुषोत्तम ॥ 1 ॥

That he takes refuge to Purushöttam Sri Ram & chants Tarak Mantra MantrāRaj (Shadakshar).

Next, Sri Gangādharāchārya is 10th Ācharya of Sri Sampraday who was initiated by Maharishi Bodhayan he was born in 535 BC;

He says in Mangalacharan of Sadhan Deepika that he got initiated by Maharishi Bodhayan;

सीतानाथ समारंभाम् बादरायण मध्यमाम्।
बोधायनाख्य गुर्वन्तां वन्दे गुरु परम्पराम् ॥

Next, Sri Sadānandachārya is 11th Acharya of Sri Sampraday and also he was the Guru Of Pushya Mitra Sungha who stopped spread of Buddhism in India. He was appered in 393 BC;

He mentioned his lineage in his work Vedant Sar-Stava;

गङ्गाधरं गुरुं नत्वा बोधायनं च राघवम्।
अहं करोमि वेदान्त्सारस्तवं सुखावहम् ॥

He clearly mentions that his Guru is Sri Gangādharāchārya.

Next, Sri Rameshwaranandacharya is 12th acharya of Sri Sampraday who was initiated by Sri Sadānandachārya. He appeared in 80 CE;

He has mentioned his lineage in his work Satprabodhamrit;

सीतानाथं नमस्कृत्य सदानन्दं गुरुं तथा ।
सत्प्रबोधामृतं कुर्वे प्राणिमृत्योर्विनाशकम्॥

Here clearly he has mentioned Sri Sadānandachārya as his Guru.

Next, Sri Dvaranandacharya is 13th acharya of Sri Sampraday who was initiated by Sri Rameshwaranandacharya. He apeeared in 140 CE;

He has mentioned his lineage in his work Prashnottar Ratnawali;

व्यासं बोधायनं रामं नत्वा रामेश्वरं गुरुम् ।
तत्त्वावबुद्धये कुर्वे प्रश्नोत्तरावलीं शुभाम्॥

He has clearly mentioned Sri Rameshwaranandacharya as his Guru & whole Sri Sampraday Guru Parampara.

Next, Sri Devanandacharya is 14th acharya of Sri Sampraday who was initiated by Sri Dvaranandacharya. He appeared in 270 CE;

He has mentioned his lineage in his work Sadachar Pradipika;

कुर्वे बोधायनं नत्वा द्वारानन्दं गुरुं तथा ।
सदाचारप्रबोधाय सदाचारप्रदीपिकाम् ॥

He has clearly mentioned Sri Dvaranandacharya as his Guru of his lineage.

Next, Sri Shyamanandacharya is 15th acharya of Sri Sampraday who was initiated by Sri Devanandacharya. He appeared in 430 CE;

He has mentioned his lineage in his work Navratni Mangalacharan;

सीतानाथं नमस्कृत्य देवानन्दं गुरुं तथा।
प्रपन्नानां हितायेयं नवरत्नी विधीयते ॥

He has clearly mentioned Sri Devanandacharya as his Guru & Remembered Sri SitaRam.

Next, Sri Shrutanandacharya is 16th acharya of Sri Sampraday who was initiated by Sri Shyamanandacharya. He apeeared in 580 CE;

He has mentioned his lineage in his work Shruti Vedya Stava;

रामं बोधायनं व्यासं गुरुदेवं प्रणम्य च।
श्रुतिवेद्यस्तवं कुर्वे श्रौतरामस्य तृप्तये॥

He has mentioned his lineage of Śrī Saṁpradāya which starts from Śrī Rām.

Next, Sri Chidanandacharya is 17th acharya of Sri Sampraday who was initiated by Sri Shrutanandacharya. He was appered in 690 CE;

He mentions his lineage in his work Prameyodesh Bhaskar;

धर्मकीत्तर्यादयो बौद्धा येन वादे निराकृताः।
तं गुरुं श्रीश्रुतानन्दं वन्दे बोधमहोदधिम् ॥
नत्वा बोधायनं व्यासं तथा रामं परमेश्वरम्।
कुर्वे प्रमयेबोधाय प्रमेयोद्देश-भास्करम् ॥

He has clearly mentioned his Guru Sri Shrutanandacharya & remembered the lineage and Lord Rama.

Next, Sri Purnanandacharya is 18th acharya of Sri Sampraday who was initiated by Sri Chidanandacharya. He was appered in 810 CE;

He has mentioned his lineage in his work Sri Ram Bhakti Vivek;

गुरुं च राघवं नत्वा व्यासं बोधायनं तथा।
रामभक्तिविवेकं हि कुर्वे भक्तिप्रदायकम्॥

He has mentioned his lineage of Sri Sampraday which starts from Sri Ram.

Next, Sri Shriyanandacharya is 19th acharya of Sri Sampraday who was initiated by Sri Purnanandacharya. He was appered in 976 CE;

He has mentioned his lineage in his work Shrautaprameyachandrika;

व्यासं बोधायानं ब्रह्म रामं नत्वा च सद्गुरुं।
कुर्वे श्रौतार्थबोधाय श्रौतप्रमेयेन्द्रिकाम् ॥

He has clearly mentioned his lineage of Sri Sampraday which starts from Sri Ram.

Next, Sri Haryānandāchārya is 20th acharya of Sri Sampraday who was initiated by Sri Shriyanandacharya. He was appered in 1100 CE;

He has mentioned his lineage in his work Charam Mantra Rāmāyaṇa;

श्रियानन्दं गुरुं नत्वा रामं बोधायनं तथा।
कुर्वे श्री चरममन्त्ररामायणं हि मुक्तिदम् ॥

He has mentioned his Guru Sri Shriyanandacharya & Lord Rāma in his Mangalacharan of his work.

Next, Sri Raghavananadacharya is 21th acharya of Sri Sampraday & also incarnation of Sri Vashistha Muni. He was initiated by Sri Haryānandāchārya & appeared in 1149 CE;

He has mentioned his lineage in his work Sri Raghavendra Mangal Mala;

राघवेन्द्रं नमस्कृत्य हर्यानन्दं गुरुं तथा ।
कुर्वे मङ्गलमालां श्रीराघवेन्द्रस्य तुष्टये ॥

He has mentioned Sri Haryānandāchārya as his Guru & hailed Sri Ram. He was the Guru of Srimad Rāmānandacharya.

And now, Ācharya Samrat Anand Bhashyakar, Hindu Dharmoodharak, Ramavatar Śrīmad Jagādgurü Ramānandacharya. He is 22nd acharya of Sri Sampraday who was initiated by Sri Raghavananadacharya. He was appered in 1299 CE;

He has mentioned his lineage in his work Gita Ānand Bhashya (commentry on Gita);

श्रीरामं जनकात्मजामनिलजं वेधो वशिष्ठावृषी योगीशं च पराशरं श्रुतिविदं व्यासं जिताक्षं शुकम्।
श्रीमन्तं पुरुषोत्तमं गुणनिधिं गङ्गाधराद्यान्यतीन् श्रीमद्राघवदेशिकं च वरदं स्वाचार्यवर्यं श्रये ॥

Srimad Ramānandacharya is also known as Father of Ghar Vapsi Movement the divinity of Bhagavad Rāmānanda attracted the hearts of 25 lacs (2.5 million) Muslims, they followed him to Ayodhyā where they came back again into their original faith of Sanātan-Vaidic-dharma after taking bath in Sarayu river, and thereafter they accepted Rāma-mantra and followed Vaishṇavism whole life.

रामानन्दस्य शिष्यो वै चायोध्यायामुपागतः । ।
कृत्वा विलोमं तं वैष्णवांस्तानकारयत् । ।
भाले त्रिशूल चिह्नं च श्वेतरक्तं तदाभवत् । ।
कण्ठे च तुलसीमाला जिहवा राममयी कृता ।।
म्लेछास्ते वैष्णवाश्चासन् रामानन्द प्रभावतः । ।
संयोगिनश्च ते ज्ञेया रामानन्दमते स्थिताः ।।
आर्याश्च वैष्णवा मुख्या अयोध्यायां बभूविरे । ।

Sri Ramananda's disciple went to Ayodhya and reversed the mantra influence of the Mlecchas and converted all those Hindus who had become Muslims to Vaishnavism. They made them into beautiful Vaishnava by putting Urdhapundra on their forehead and red tilak in the middle, putting a garland of Tulsi around their neck and putting the mantra of Ram Naam in their mouth. All the Muslims became superior Aryans under the influence of Ramananda and began to live in Ayodhya.

(Śrī Bhavishya Purān 3/21/52–55)

What Śrīmad Jagādgurü Ramānandacharya said, he shown it by accepting even Malechha (Muslim Śrī Kabir), Shudra (Śrī Raidās, a cobbler), and women (Śrī Padmāvati and Śrī Sursuri ji) as his direct disciples... who all became renowned Gurus, and Bhakti-movement saints. Thus, Jagadgurutva (being the universal teacher) is fully culminated in Bhagavad Śrī Rāmānanda in every way.

जगमंगल आधार भक्ति दसधा के आगर॥
(श्रीभक्तमाल पद - ३६)

That's why Sri NābhaDas Ji Maharaj has said, रामानंद उदार सुधानिधि अवनि कल्पतरु, He was very generous, his approach was not narrow in adopting the refugees. (Jagadguru Śrīmad Rāmānandācharya ji adopted people of all castes, gender etc. he did not hesitate to adopt even Malechha, that is why the word “Udāar" (Generous) has been exclusively used for him.